# Jenkins edit config in multi-branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I cannot find a way to edit the configuration of multibranch pipeline projects. When I change to the branch level, there is only a "view configuration" menu item, as opposed to ordinary pipeline projects.

I am looking for a method to configure build triggers from outside Jenkins. My current workaround (define a pipeline per branch) is not feasible beyond initial testing.

Comment: I think I have the same problem, each pipeline of a multi-branch pipeline project can't be save : there is no save/apply button... Do you have this behaviour ?

Comment: @Wimateeka is correct: the multibranch pipeline can be configured via web ui, and each branch configuration is defined via Jenkinsfile in source control.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the *overall* configuration of a multi-branch pipeline project, such as the repo it will read from and any credentials it will need, triggers for scanning the branch to check for changes (**Note: not the same as build triggers**),orphaned item strategy, build configuration, properties, and a few other things. This can be viewed by clicking "Configuration" on the page that shows all the branches, or it will say it is empty if there are none.

Please note this **only applies to multibranch pipelines that are not part of an organizational folder (not a "Bitbucket Team/Project" or "GitHub Organization" type project.)**

[image]
[image]

---

If you click a branch name (ex: master), clicking "View Configuration" will only let you view it. You have to edit the file defining that pipeline on the correct branch in order to change it. In the case of these screen shots, you need to edit the `Jenkinsfile` in the `Test-Multibranch-Job` repo on the `master` branch to edit the configuration.

To add a trigger mechanism, you could add `triggers { gitlab(<config-here>) }` to your `Jenkinsfile` if your repo is in Gitlab. Also note whether you are using a [declarative pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) or a [scripted pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) because the syntaxes are different.

[image]
[image]

NOTE: I am running Jenkins ver. 2.92

Comment: This is not true for multibranch pipelines, which are part of an organizational folder. See @eversMcc's comment

Comment: @SilverJan Which part is not true? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The editing part. For a multibranch pipeline which is part of an organizational folder (e.g. Bitbucket or GitHub), you cannot edit the configuration after the initial setup. This is also what is mentioned in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33900?focusedCommentId=326208&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-326208

Comment: Are you talking about a "Bitbucket Team/Project" or "GitHub Organization"? I have never used those before. I can edit the answer to specify that the multibranch pipeline can be configured via web ui, and each branch configuration is defined via Jenkinsfile in source control only for Multibranch pipelines/workflows not in organization folders. If you have a solution for how to edit a multibranch pipeline that is part of an organization folder, you should post it here for others to read. Also the asker of this question never specified what project type they were using.

Comment: Personally I experienced it in a Bitbucket Team / Project. However, according to the Jenkins Jira issue, it applies for both. A solution is not there as it is by design (as per Jenkins Jira issue comment). Thanks for adding that piece of information into your answer!

Answer (score 2):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33900

*"As designed, these jobs are view-only."* -- Jesse Glick

you should be able to define the config in the pipeline itself, e.g. https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Comment: My requirement is to trigger builds on git commits without exposing Jenkins to the outside. So periodical jobs do not work in my case.

Comment: Are you using gitlab, or github? If gitlab, you can set the gitlab connection up in Jenkins in "Manage Jenkins >> Configure System", in gitlab create a webhook that'll post to the '/project' endpoint for the job in Jenkins, then specify all the configuration (the crux of what you're trying to achieve) in a `triggers{gitlab(<config-here>)}` section in your Jenkinsfile.  See https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#jenkins-job-configuration for more detail on what config you can specify (triggerOnPush: true, might suit you)

Comment: ..and if you want to have different configuration for different branches, you could specify different `triggers{gitlab(<config-here>)}` in each branch/Jenkinsfile, and use 'branchFilterType', 'includeBranchesSpec' and/or 'excludeBranchesSpec' config options   (I've not personally attempted that, though)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to edit a Multibranch configuration, for example to configure Multibranch Action Triggers which have no Jenkinsfile configuration, you can go edit the configuration file directly on your server, in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/NAMEOFPROJECT/config.xml